# How to slice individual columns (with values) in an ActiveRecord::Result in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a Rails query which is shown below:

```rb
query_results = 
  User.
    joins("INNER JOIN posts ON posts.user_id = users.user_id").
    select("posts.topic, posts.thread_id")
```

`query_results` contains values of 2 columns: `topic` and `thread_id`.

I would like to split `query_results` into **2 arrays** - 1 containing values from all records (from `query_results`) for column `topic` alone and the 2nd containing values from all records for column `thread_id` alone.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Try This out can help you!

**here we are going to use pluck.**

Yes. [According to Rails guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pluck), pluck directly converts a database result into an array, without constructing ActiveRecord objects. This means better performance for a large or often-running query.

```
topic_arr = []
thread_id = []
query_results = User.joins("INNER JOIN posts ON posts.user_id = users.user_id").pluck("posts.topic, posts.thread_id")
query_results.each do |i|
    topic_arr.push(i.first)
    thread_id.push(i.last)
end
puts query_results #=>[["topic1", 1], ["topic2", 2], ["topic3", 3]]
puts topic_arr #=>["topic1","topic2","topic3"]
puts thread_id #=>[1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try below code for your requirement :-

```
query_results = 
  User.
    joins("INNER JOIN posts ON posts.user_id = users.user_id").
   pluck("posts.topic, posts.thread_id").to_h

topic_arr = query_results.keys
thread_id_arr = query_results.values
```

**Example** 
Above query will give you result like:-

```
query_results = {"topic 1"=>1, "topic 2" => 2} 
topic_arr = query_results.keys
topic_arr = ["topic 1", "topic 2"] 

thread_id_arr = query_results.values
thread_id_arr = [1, 2]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I need to select 3 columns instead f 2, how should I modify the above code?

Comment: In that case you have to use each loop and push one by one in separate array because **.to_h** method is possible only for two values :)